# CSS3 Centering Image while Rotating

Tags: html, css, css-animations, css-transforms

So the basic problem I'm having is that I want to have a rotating vortex which is positioned in the middle of their respective divs.  When I try to have a transform:translate outside of the animation, it doesn't get activated, and if I try to call it within the animation, the image rotates around the top left corner.  I can't seem to figure out how to both center the image vertically and horizontally, and have it rotate at the same time.

Here is the code I am working with:

```
div img
{
    position: absolute;
    display:block;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;

    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

    margin: auto;
    width:auto;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 70%;
    max-width: 70%;




    -webkit-animation: rotate 3s linear infinite 0s;
    -moz-animation: rotateup 3s linear infinite 0s;
    -o-animation: rotate 3s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: rotate 3s linear infinite 0s;
    animation: rotate 3s linear infinite 0s
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
 from {
     -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
}
to {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);                                 
}
```

and here is a fiddle demonstrating my problem.  http://jsfiddle.net/4j7T4/

Thanks for all of the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would spin the div and not the image maybe. Also, I would center it differently. Try this: Are you using sass or autoprefixr? If not, you should check it out. I'm using a block element modifier for the `.image-w` which is good for responsive images and stuff, and a little `@mxin` for reuse on absolutely positioned center stuff. The margin auto does the trick as long as you specify height and width of what you want to center. Here is [a codepen.](http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/iItaz)

### HTML

```
<div class="image-w spinner"><img src="http://placehold.it/400x400" alt="spinner" /></div>
```

### SCSS

```
.image-w {
  //
  img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}

@mixin absolute-center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0;
  bottom: 0; left: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.spinner {
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  @include absolute-center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: rotate 3s linear infinite 0s
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
  animation: rotate 3s linear infinite 0s
}
```

Comment: Rotating the div was what I ended up doing, I probably wouldn't have thought of that! Thanks, and I'll look into sass, it looks like it make css a bit friendlier

Answer (score 2):

Here is an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4j7T4/2/).

Since the width of the div is 30px and the height is 30px, you place a margin-left and margin-top of -15px (or negative half of the width/height)

```
{
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
```

Another example with just a square http://jsfiddle.net/tb5Bg/

Comment: I see how that would work for something of a fixed size, like my example fiddle, but what I am actually using is and image with width and height both at auto with a max of 50%.  I tried using margin-top and left at -50% but that just returned it back to where it was before the top and left.